# PHPUnit: Error: Class not found even while importing the class

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I literally copied and pasted code from the relevant files from a Laracasts video by Jeffrey Way: https://github.com/laracasts/Code-Katas-in-PHP/tree/master/prime-factors

```
<?php

use App\PrimeFactors;

class PrimeFactorsTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @dataProvider factors
     */
    function it_generates_prime_factors($number, $expected)
    {
        $factors = new PrimeFactors();

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $factors->generate($number));
    }

    public function factors()
    {
        return [
            [1, []],
            [2, [2]],
            [3, [3]],
            [4, [2, 2]],
            [5, [5]],
            [6, [2, 3]],
            [7, [7]],
            [8, [2, 2, 2]],
            [9, [3, 3]],
            [11, [11]],
            [12, [2, 2, 3]],
            [17, [17]],
            [100, [2, 2, 5, 5]]
        ];
    }

}
```

Yet, whenever I run this command: `phpunit filename`, I get an error telling me this: `Class 'App\PrimeFactors' not found`.

Even though on line 3 I'm importing the namespace with the class: `use App\PrimeFactors;`

So, must there be a problem with my autoloading in composer.json?

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at other posts with the same problem but the solutions to those didn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, that tutorial/code is 6 years old, some things might have changed. Have you made sure that `App\PrimeFactors` actually exists? Is there an `"autoload-dev":` section in your `composer.json`? Try running `composer dumpautoload` to reload dependencies. Are your files actually in a `src` folder? Latest Laravel version have `"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },` in `composer.json`

Comment: If you are using PHPStorm follow this to get things working: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-phpunit-framework.html# .  I had the same problem and this solved it for me. One caveat is that I had to use Phpunit ~8.5 because PHPstorm didn't want to work with version 9.

Comment: @mtrueblood I'm using VSCode.

Comment: @kerbholz Yes it exists. I changed autoload to autoload-dev and I get the same result. I've ran dump-autoload and the file is in the src folder. Stil same result. This isn't a Laravel app. Just plain PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the class "PrimeFactors" has no namespace. Try to add this line: `namespace App;` in "PrimeFactors" class.